# python-for-android - подскажите с командой для терминала

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, kivy, apk

Я написал для теста программу

```py
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.config(bg='blue')
root.geometry('320x480')
root.title('Test for android')

but = Button(root, text='Click me')
but.config(width=35, height=2, fg='black', bg='gray')
but.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

и мне надо её скомпилить в .apk для Android.
Вот МАКЕТ команды в CMD
`p4a apk --requirements=kivy --private /home/username/devel/planewave_frozen/ --package=net.inclem.planewavessdl2 --name="planewavessdl2" --version=0.5 --bootstrap=sdl2`

Можете схематически мне пояснить как работает эта команда? Где и что нужно вставить и т.д? Возможно это очень глупый вопрос, но всё же. Помогите

Использую для этой цели **python-for-android** - https://github.com/kivy/python-for-android

Comment: Даже для собственных целей большинство разработчиков посоветуют вам держаться подальше от Tkinter. Это устаревшая и не интуитивно понятная библиотека, которая часто делает создание и обслуживание графического интерфейса сложнее, чем нужно.

Comment: Основным преимуществом разработки приложений с использованием библиотеки Python и встраивания в Android является кроссплатформенная поддержка. Эти библиотеки часто позволяют легко переносить ваше приложение на множество различных операционных систем.

Comment: Я не буду отвечать, что является "лучшим", так как это вопрос, основанный на мнении, выходящий за рамки StackOverflow, однако я скажу, что (как правило) легче переносить с Kivy на Android, чем в некоторых других библиотеках (таких как Qt).). Но возьми это с крошкой соли. Большинство библиотек в настоящее время предлагают расширенные встроенные возможности графического интерфейса, и ваш выбор, скорее всего, не ограничит вас в этом отношении.

Comment: В любом случае, нет прямого/простого способа перевести ваш проект Tkinter в любой из них, и вам, вероятно, придется переписать его с библиотекой, которую вы выберете.

Comment: Да чего вы так заморочились) Я TKinter взял чисто для примера. Мне нужно узнать просто как работает python-for-android от Kivy

Comment: В документации все кратко написано, зайдите на kivu git.Если вас интересует способ установки то вот видео, которое полностью объясняет.https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IzKJgpJrrQU

Comment: Спасибо большое